# RabbitMQ change listeners.tcp.default port is not changed how is expected

Tags: rabbitmq

Through Homebrew I have installed RabbitMQ.

It starts with `./rabbitmq-server` without any problem:

```
  ##  ##
  ##  ##      RabbitMQ 3.7.6. Copyright (C) 2007-2018 Pivotal Software, Inc.
  ##########  Licensed under the MPL.  See http://www.rabbitmq.com/
  ######  ##
  ##########  Logs: /usr/local/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost.log
                    /usr/local/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost_upgrade.log

              Starting broker...
 completed with 6 plugins.
```

I have read the following:

- [RabbitMQ Configuration](https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html)
- [rabbitmq.conf.example](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/blob/master/docs/rabbitmq.conf.example)
- [rabbitmq_conf_homebrew](https://gist.github.com/robcowie/1317580)

Thus in the `/usr/local/etc/rabbitmq` path exists:

- `enabled_plugins`
- `rabbitmq-env.conf`
- `rabbitmq.conf` (created manually)

The content of these files are:

**enabled_plugins**

```
[rabbitmq_management,rabbitmq_stomp,rabbitmq_amqp1_0,rabbitmq_mqtt].
```

**rabbitmq-env.conf**

```
CONFIG_FILE=/usr/local/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq
NODE_IP_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1
NODENAME=rabbit@localhost
```

**rabbitmq.conf**

```
# listeners.tcp.default = 5672
listeners.tcp.default = 5662
#listeners.tcp.local = 127.0.0.1:5662 <-- Alpha
#listeners.tcp.local_v6 = ::1:5662 <-- Beta

# mqtt.listeners.tcp.default = 1883
mqtt.listeners.tcp.default = 1873

# stomp.listeners.tcp.default = 61613
stomp.listeners.tcp.default = 61603
```

The purpose with the ports are decrease them by -10 each one. It only works for `mqtt` and `stomp`. The `listeners.tcp.default` value is ignored, it remains how `5672` and not with `5662` how is expected. I can confirm this showing the `/usr/local/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost.log` content, as follows:

```
...
2018-07-29 12:46:31.461 [info] <0.321.0> Starting message stores for vhost '/'
2018-07-29 12:46:31.461 [info] <0.325.0> Message store "628WB79CIFDYO9LJI6DKMI09L/msg_store_transient": using rabbit_msg_store_ets_index to provide index
2018-07-29 12:46:31.465 [info] <0.321.0> Started message store of type transient for vhost '/'
2018-07-29 12:46:31.465 [info] <0.328.0> Message store "628WB79CIFDYO9LJI6DKMI09L/msg_store_persistent": using rabbit_msg_store_ets_index to provide index
2018-07-29 12:46:31.490 [info] <0.321.0> Started message store of type persistent for vhost '/'
2018-07-29 12:46:31.495 [info] <0.363.0> started TCP Listener on 127.0.0.1:5672
2018-07-29 12:46:31.495 [info] <0.223.0> Setting up a table for connection tracking on this node: tracked_connection_on_node_rabbit@localhost
2018-07-29 12:46:31.495 [info] <0.223.0> Setting up a table for per-vhost connection counting on this node: tracked_connection_per_vhost_on_node_rabbit@localhost
2018-07-29 12:46:31.496 [info] <0.33.0> Application rabbit started on node rabbit@localhost
2018-07-29 12:46:31.496 [info] <0.369.0> rabbit_stomp: default user 'guest' enabled
2018-07-29 12:46:31.497 [info] <0.385.0> started STOMP TCP Listener on [::]:61603
2018-07-29 12:46:31.497 [info] <0.33.0> Application rabbitmq_stomp started on node rabbit@localhost
2018-07-29 12:46:31.497 [info] <0.33.0> Application cowboy started on node rabbit@localhost
2018-07-29 12:46:31.498 [info] <0.33.0> Application rabbitmq_web_dispatch started on node rabbit@localhost
2018-07-29 12:46:31.572 [info] <0.33.0> Application rabbitmq_management_agent started on node rabbit@localhost
2018-07-29 12:46:31.600 [info] <0.438.0> Management plugin started. Port: 15672
2018-07-29 12:46:31.600 [info] <0.544.0> Statistics database started.
2018-07-29 12:46:31.601 [info] <0.33.0> Application rabbitmq_management started on node rabbit@localhost
2018-07-29 12:46:31.601 [info] <0.33.0> Application rabbitmq_amqp1_0 started on node rabbit@localhost
2018-07-29 12:46:31.601 [info] <0.557.0> MQTT retained message store: rabbit_mqtt_retained_msg_store_dets
2018-07-29 12:46:31.621 [info] <0.575.0> started MQTT TCP Listener on [::]:1873
2018-07-29 12:46:31.622 [info] <0.33.0> Application rabbitmq_mqtt started on node rabbit@localhost
2018-07-29 12:46:31.622 [notice] <0.94.0> Changed loghwm of /usr/local/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost.log to 50
2018-07-29 12:46:31.882 [info] <0.5.0> Server startup complete; 6 plugins started.
 * rabbitmq_mqtt
 * rabbitmq_amqp1_0
 * rabbitmq_management
 * rabbitmq_management_agent
 * rabbitmq_web_dispatch
 * rabbitmq_stomp
```

Thus from above:

- `started TCP Listener on 127.0.0.1:5672` should be **5662**
- `started STOMP TCP Listener on [::]:61603` changed how is expected
- `Management plugin started. Port: 15672` is not necessary change it
- `started MQTT TCP Listener on [::]:1873`changed how is expected

I have the same behaviour if I enable `Alpha` and `Beta`.

The server is stopped with `./rabbitmqctl stop` and started again with `./rabbitmq-server`

What is missing or wrong?

Comment: The log file will show what configuration files were read upon startup. Please ensure the expected files are actually being used.